# How can I zoom into an ImageView without it jumping slightly elsewhere? (Android)

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, pinchzoom, translate-animation

I'm trying to create an application in which the user can drag and zoom an ImageView. But I'm experiencing problems with the following code.

When the scaleFactor is not 1 and the second finger gets down it is translated a little to somewhere else. I don't know where this translate comes from...

Here's the complete class:

```
package me.miutaltbati.ramaview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import static android.view.MotionEvent.INVALID_POINTER_ID;

public class RamaView extends ImageView {
    private Context context;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix translateMatrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();

    // Properties coming from outside:
    private int drawableLayoutId;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private static float MIN_ZOOM = 0.33333F;
    private static float MAX_ZOOM = 5F;

    private PointF mLastTouch = new PointF(0, 0);
    private PointF mLastFocus = new PointF(0, 0);
    private PointF mLastPivot = new PointF(0, 0);
    private float mPosX = 0F;
    private float mPosY = 0F;

    public float scaleFactor = 1F;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private Paint paint;
    private Bitmap bitmapLayout;

    private OnFactorChangedListener mListener;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    public RamaView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeInConstructor(context);
    }

    public RamaView(Context context, @android.support.annotation.Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initializeInConstructor(context);
    }

    public RamaView(Context context, @android.support.annotation.Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initializeInConstructor(context);
    }

    public void initializeInConstructor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        paint = new Paint();
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        mScaleDetector.setQuickScaleEnabled(false);

        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap() {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inMutable = true;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableLayoutId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = Util.calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height); // e.g.: 4, 8

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableLayoutId, options);
    }

    public void setDrawable(int drawableId) {
        drawableLayoutId = drawableId;
    }

    public void setSize(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        bitmapLayout = decodeSampledBitmap();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Remember where we started (for dragging)
                mLastTouch = new PointF(x, y);

                // Save the ID of this pointer (for dragging)
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    mLastFocus = new PointF(mScaleDetector.getFocusX(), mScaleDetector.getFocusY());
                }
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
                int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);

                float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Calculate the distance moved
                float dx = 0;
                float dy = 0;

                if (event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
                    // Calculate the distance moved
                    dx = x - mLastTouch.x;
                    dy = y - mLastTouch.y;

                    matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, mLastPivot.x, mLastPivot.y);

                    // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                    mLastTouch = new PointF(x, y);
                } else if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    // Calculate the distance moved
                    dx = mScaleDetector.getFocusX() - mLastFocus.x;
                    dy = mScaleDetector.getFocusY() - mLastFocus.y;

                    matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, -mPosX + mScaleDetector.getFocusX(), -mPosY + mScaleDetector.getFocusY());

                    mLastPivot = new PointF(-mPosX + mScaleDetector.getFocusX(), -mPosY + mScaleDetector.getFocusY());
                    mLastFocus = new PointF(mScaleDetector.getFocusX(), mScaleDetector.getFocusY());
                }

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                matrix.postTranslate(mPosX, mPosY);

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouch = new PointF(event.getX(newPointerIndex), event.getY(newPointerIndex));
                    mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                } else {
                    final int tempPointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    mLastTouch = new PointF(event.getX(tempPointerIndex), event.getY(tempPointerIndex));
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();

        canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapLayout, 0, 0, paint);

        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is on this line:

```
matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, -mPosX + mScaleDetector.getFocusX(), -mPosY + mScaleDetector.getFocusY());
```

I tried a lot of things but I couldn't get it to work properly.

**UPDATE:**

Here's how you can init a RamaView instance:

Main activity's onCreate:

```
rvRamaView = findViewById(R.id.rvRamaView);

final int[] rvSize = new int[2];
ViewTreeObserver vto = rvRamaView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        rvRamaView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        rvSize[0] = rvRamaView.getMeasuredWidth();
        rvSize[1] = rvRamaView.getMeasuredHeight();

        rvRamaView.setSize(rvSize[0], rvSize[1]);
        return true;
    }
});

rvRamaView.setDrawable(R.drawable.original_jpg);
```

Comment: I tried to run your RamaView class at follows: `RamaView ramaView = findViewById(R.id.ramaView); ramaView.setDrawable(R.drawable.photo); ramaView.setSize(500, 500);` But at runtime I only get a black view even if I make one or two fingers gestures. How do you init the RamaView?

Comment: @ffernandez It should work. I updated the question how I init it.

Comment: [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) is ready to use and really intuitive to extend library for that requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use the matrix to *accumulate* changes rather than try to recalculate the transformations yourself. You can do this with the matrix  *post...* and *pre...* methods and stay away from the *set...* methods which reset the matrix.

Here is a rework of the *RamaView* class which was largely on target except for the specific handling of the matrix as noted above. The mods are to the *onTouchEvent()* method. The video is output of the code working in a sample app.

[image]

**RamaView.java**

```
public class RamaView extends ImageView {
    private final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // Properties coming from outside:
    private int drawableLayoutId;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 0.33333F;
    private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 5F;

    private PointF mLastTouch = new PointF(0, 0);
    private PointF mLastFocus = new PointF(0, 0);

    public float scaleFactor = 1F;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private Paint paint;
    private Bitmap bitmapLayout;

    //    private OnFactorChangedListener mListener;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    public RamaView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeInConstructor(context);
    }

    public RamaView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initializeInConstructor(context);
    }

    public RamaView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initializeInConstructor(context);
    }

    public void initializeInConstructor(Context context) {
        paint = new Paint();
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        mScaleDetector.setQuickScaleEnabled(false);

        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap() {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inMutable = true;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableLayoutId, options);

        options.inSampleSize = Util.calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height); // e.g.: 4, 8

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableLayoutId, options);
    }

    public void setDrawable(int drawableId) {
        drawableLayoutId = drawableId;
    }

    public void setSize(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        bitmapLayout = decodeSampledBitmap();
    }

    private float mLastScaleFactor = 1.0f;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Remember where we started (for dragging)
                mLastTouch = new PointF(x, y);

                // Save the ID of this pointer (for dragging)
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    mLastFocus = new PointF(mScaleDetector.getFocusX(), mScaleDetector.getFocusY());
                }
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
                int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);

                float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Calculate the distance moved
                float dx = 0;
                float dy = 0;

                if (event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
                    // Calculate the distance moved
                    dx = x - mLastTouch.x;
                    dy = y - mLastTouch.y;

                    // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                    mLastTouch = new PointF(x, y);
                } else if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    // Calculate the distance moved
                    float focusX = mScaleDetector.getFocusX();
                    float focusY = mScaleDetector.getFocusY();
                    dx = focusX - mLastFocus.x;
                    dy = focusY - mLastFocus.y;

                    // Since we are accumating translation/scaling, we are just adding to
                    // the previous scale.
                    matrix.postScale(scaleFactor/mLastScaleFactor, scaleFactor/mLastScaleFactor, focusX, focusY);
                    mLastScaleFactor = scaleFactor;

                    mLastFocus = new PointF(focusX, focusY);
                }

                // Translation is cumulative.
                matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouch = new PointF(event.getX(newPointerIndex), event.getY(newPointerIndex));
                    mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                } else {
                    final int tempPointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    mLastTouch = new PointF(event.getX(tempPointerIndex), event.getY(tempPointerIndex));
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();

        canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapLayout, 0, 0, paint);

        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You provided the answer I was looking for. Now I also understand what I did wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code is not complete (e. g. I cannot see how matrix is used and where scaleFactor is assigned), but I think the reason why the translation is inconsistent is because in case of 2 pointers you get the [x, y] position from the `mScaleDetector.getFocus`. As the documentation for `ScaleGestureDetector.getFocusX()` states:

> Get the X coordinate of the current gesture's focal point. If a
>   gesture is in progress, the focal point is between each of the
>   pointers forming the gesture.

You should use the `mScaleDetector` only for getting the current scale, but translation should be always calculated as the difference between the `mLastTouch` and `event.getXY(pointerIndex)` so that only one pointer is considered for translation. In case the user adds a second finger and releases the first one, make sure to reassign the `pointerIndex` and do not perform any translation to avoid jumping.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I updated to code, it is now the complete class. A little modification has been done, this is the best I could come up with so far. Now the only problem is, it jumps when the second finger gets down.

Comment: I also tried what you recommended (to translate only with one finger), but in that case when scaling the focal point wouldn't be the center of the two fingers (because it is continuously translated too). I need to translate by the focal point.